Creality K1 Max first layer issue
I have a brand new Creality K1 Max, it works pretty well but with some filaments (not Creality) I have some problems on the first layer:

The picture taken shows the bottom side of the first layer, that is, the side that touches the bed. In some areas (like the rightmost edge of the picture), it is perfect: there are no lines. Instead, the central and left parts of the picture show the issue. There are many lines in relief, and this is not desirable.
Almost all my objects rely on the bottom part of the first layer to produce a smooth finish (this is the side that will be exposed, let's say the surface of a box). I cannot live with these defects.
I'm aware the bed is not super-even:

but should be compensated by the machine itself, otherwise what's the purpose of probing and strain gauges? Anyway, I'm going to try to insert some shims to reduce the inclination of the bed.
Here is another example, it's always the bottom side of the first layer:

It seems severely under extruded to me.
I tried to slightly reduce the Z-offset (by 0.05 mm, even though it should be perfect by the factory calibration) and increase the flow for the first layer (1.02). It's printing right now. As soon as it has finished, I'll update the question with the results.
Here are the results:

There are some improvements, but the printing is still far from optimal.
I'm using the GEEETECH Pla wood filament with the following parameters:

nozzle temperature: 200 °C (selected after temperature tower)
bed temperature: 50 °C
the others are the default ones from the standard profile in Creality Print

The printed objects are quite good but often the first layer of large ones exhibits the above issue. I performed the calibration of the printed twice.
It happens only in a few areas, not in all parts of the first layer.
Given the picture what can cause this problem and what can I do to fix it?
UPDATE
I tried to:

slow down to 30 mm/s for first layer
improved the bed alignement, almost flat in the central area:



increased the flow for the first layer up to 30%

With all these tweaks, I'm still far from an acceptable quality:

I can't go closer to the bed with the nozzle because at Z = 0.00 mm a sheet of paper cannot be dragged easily.
